# FreeBSD - Running Python code in different processors

Tags: python, multicore, freebsd

I want to run two python scripts.
Each one takes long time to complete.
I am working on a dual core FreeBSD machine and want to make sure that I use both the cores.
When I run both the scripts I find that both end up running in the same CPU.
How can I control that two scripts are taken by different CPUs?
I know in Linux we can specify taskset -c X python foo.py where X is the CPU number liks 0,1,2.
How can I do something similar in FreeBSD system.

Comment: These days, kernels are good at distributing workload. What is your evidence that your processes are running on the same core?

Answer (score 2):

The term you are looking for is "CPU affinity."

`cpuset -c -l X python foo.py`

See [How to set CPU affinity for a process in FreeBSD](http://segfault.in/2010/09/how-to-set-cpu-affinity-for-a-process-in-freebsd/) for more details.

Comment: I get cpuset: setaffinity: Operation not permitted

Comment: Did you try running the command as root (or prefixing with `sudo`)? sudo doesn't come with some freebsd distributions by default. To check yours: `pkg_info -xI sudo`. For details on your version: `pkg_info | grep sudo` to get a version, and assuming version 1.6.9.20, `pkg_info -do sudo-1.6.9.20` to find more details.